# Calculate Essential and Fundamental matrices using a calibrated camera using 4 co-planar point matches

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, 3d-reconstruction

Suppose I have two images of a scene with four co-planar 3D points and their corresponding 2D points in the images. I also have the camera calibration matrix, ***K***.

I can then estimate the relative poses of the cameras using i.e. [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-014-0725-5)]. Then, given ***R***, ***t*** (from the pose) and ***K*** I can calculate the Essential matrix and then the Fundamental matrix.

**Is the resulting Fundamental matrix deficient in any way because it is calculated from only four co-planar points?**

Comment: point *pairs* (four in each image), so your eight values imply eight equations, right? at least for homographies, they're usually scaled so the bottom right value is 1.

Comment: No it is only one equation per point correspondence. See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/40289

Comment: After thinking about it a second time, I think you may be right. The difference between my problem and the on in the linked question is that I know the position of the 3D points. Maybe that gives eight equations?

Comment: yeah I'm playing a little loose with the terminology. a 2d-2d mapping, a homography, requires four point pairs (so 16 values). the homography has 8 degrees nailed down from that input. your having 3D points in the middle is additional information that doesn't affect the outcome. it's still a 2d-2d mapping. the planes being image planes doesn't matter, could be any other planes in space. these matrices (homography as well as E, F) cannot recover 3D information, so the assumption is that the points always lie in a plane.

Comment: I can't claim to provide any truth here, just hints that might send you on the right track (or not). it's been a long time since I dealt with E and F at all and not very thoroughly either. I strongly suspect that they too have 8 degrees of freedom determined by input data and the 9th customarily being the bottom right coefficient of the matrix, the matrix being scaled so it's 1.

Answer (score 0):

Four coplanar points are not sufficient to determine a fundamental (i.e. uncalibrated) or essential (calibrated) matrix. You may only constrain a homography using them, which is all you need anyway if the scene of interest is indeed on a plane.